# Python interaction with browser (Raspberry WebioPi)

Tags: javascript, python, html, raspberry-pi, webiopi

I use a tool called "webiopi" to control a wellness device via a Raspberry pi and a relay board. This tool connect buttons on a webpage with a Python script.
I can read the state (low/high) from the GPIO pins on the buttons i've created.

What i want is to show values from the script in the browser. 
(Like ' temperature_measured'  or. 'Calculated_time')

Is there a way i can show output from the python script to the webbrowser?

```
    button = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro", "Normaal", "Prog1");
    $("#top").append(button)

<div id="content" align="center">
<td>    
  </td>
                            {{print here output from script.py}}
      <div id="top"></div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a this forum  [Wpio forum][1]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webiopi/DreW_74gm0o

gives Pete Dudash the answer to this question, which i copy here

Yes, this is possible. What you’re looking to do is add a callback routine to your javascript. First you execute some action in javascript (either from a button press or a timer) and call a python macro. This time, you specify a call back routine when calling the macro. The call back routine receives data from the macro and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Javascript:

```
function getPythonResponse() {
// "sendData" is the name of the macro you specify in your script.py
// "[]" is an empty list.  If you want to send data for the macro to use, you would include that here
// "handlePythonResponse" is the name of the callback routine that will execute once the python macro is finished
webiopi().callMacro("sendData", [], handlePythonResponse);
```

}

```
var handlePythonResponse = function(macro, args, response) {
// "response" is the variable that holds the data from script.py
// Now we can apply those results to the webpage by assigning the value to the "pythonResult" id.  This is the element in your HTML where you want to print the info.
$("#pythonResult").text(response);
```

}

Python:

```
@webiopi.macro
```

def sendData():

HTML:

```
<div id="content" align="center">
<td></td>

<span id="pythonResult">{{print here output from script.py}}</span>

<div id="top"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to call the script and echo the output to the page. You'll need PHP installed and enabled, and the file must end with `.php`. If you know the webserver you are using, I can give you some additional help. Also note that the script should print all information it wants on the web page into standard output.

```
    button = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro", "Normaal", "Prog1");
    $("#top").append(button)

<div id="content" align="center">
<td>    
  </td>
      <?php exec("python myscript.py", $out); echo $out; ?>
      <div id="top"></div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this what I absolutely don't want. I already have to deal with Javascript and Python, which are totally new to me. I don't want PHP which is also new to to me. However, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Well, in case you don't know Perl, this is the easiest solution.